# ¿Como hacer que mis correos lleguen al destino sin secureserver.net?

Tags: php, html5, wordpress, smtp

Estoy haciendo un formulario a mano en **Wordpress** y quiero que llegue a un correo en especial, entonces ya hice el código:

```
$name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['name']);
$email = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);
$destination = $_POST['destination'];

$adminmail = "email@dedestino.com"; //email destino
$subject = 'Formulario de cotizar'; //asunto
$headers = "Reply-to: " . $name . " <" . $email . ">";

//Cuerpo del mensaje
    $msg = "Nombre: " . $name . "\n";
    $msg .= "E-mail: " . $email . "\n\n";
    $msg .= "Paquete de Interés:" . $destination . "\n";

$sendmail = mail( $adminmail, $subject, $msg, $headers);
```

El problema es el siguiente: supongamos que **juan@viajes.com** lleno el formulario y lo envió, entonces, cuando los correos llegan, llegan así:

**de:   viajes@ip-192-169-232-234.secureserver.net**

en ves de que lleguen así:

**de: juan@viajes.com**

¿Como puedo cambiar esto (**viajes@ip-192-169-232-234.secureserver.net**) por esto (**juan@viajes.com**)?

Answer (score 0):

La **solución** es la siguiente amigos:

```
// Function to change sender name
function wpb_sender_name( $original_email_from ) {
    return ''.$_POST['name'];
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'wpb_sender_name' );

// Function to change email address
function wpb_sender_email( $original_email_address ) {
    return ''.$_POST['email'];
} 

add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'wpb_sender_email' );
```

Donde **$_POST['name']** y **$_POST['email']** son el nombre y el correo con el que se va a enviar el correo.

**Es así que los correos se envían con el nombre y el correo de la persona que lleno el formulario de manera dinámica.**